# Please explain Bamboo (Plan, Branch, and the build-dir)

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

So I feel like this is a pretty basic question but I'm not wrapping my head around this.

**In Bamboo, how do you remove the folders in build-dir after the code has been merged?** I currently have 21 directories of checked out code, with only 5 active plan branches (develop + 4 active pull request).

**Also, what is with the folder names?** I have PROJ-DAPP[x]-JOB1, and PROJ-SMIT[x]-JOB1 (with SMIT being from my last name, and x being various numbers or no number). I'm thinking these somehow tie to the plan name but not fully sure. (it was PROJ_SMITH, but now is PROJ_Basic)

Our setup:

- Single agent (bamboo-agent)
- Basic single stage plan, with checkout & compile (successfully showing passed)
- Create new branch when pull request is generated (working successfully)
- Force Clean Build-checked
- Delete Branch after 1 day inactivity or 7 days after delete

Answer (score 0):

> In Bamboo, how do you remove the folders in build-dir after the code has been merged?

Even though your setup is deleting branches and force cleaning builds, you will still get multiple folders on the system.  This is because Bamboo keeps previous builds for logging 
 and artifacts.  However, you can configure how long and how many builds Bamboo keeps.  The best way to do this is under settings go to Administration and then select Expiry.  From here you can set how many builds your project will keep and when it will update.  If you need space you can go into the build-xml folder and delete some of the older builds manually, but this may cause issues in Bamboo if you try to load logs or artifacts for that build.

> Also, what is with the folder names?

The folder names are built on Plan Key, Job, and Build number.  The structure and convention may vary depending on whether your build has multiple stages and plans.

Comment: So under Expiry I have set the following, but have not seen any folders deleted.

Override global build expiry configuration (checked)
What should expire: Build Results, Build artifacts, and Build Logs (all checked)
Expire after 1 Days

Min/Max number builds to keep is blank.

Is there something I need to do for that to remove the old items? (old meaning before I updated this setting).


Also, we have a single stage/single plan setup. So I assume the name is ProjectName-PlanKey[build number]-Job??

Comment: You need to initiate the expiry under the settings.  Even though you set custom settings, it will not scan and remove until the service is triggered.  For the folder names it may follow the first one is ProjectName-PlanKey-JobKey.  Older builds will be ProjectName-PlaneKey[BuildNumber]-JobKey.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but how do I "initiate" it. I have the settings configured, but I don't know how I 'trigger' the servcie so that it goes through and cleans up based on my new expiration settings.

Comment: Under "Expiry" from the admin menu you can choose "Run Now" under the Removal Schedule header.

Comment: Wesley, thanks for all your help. I've got a better understanding now and am working with our Bamboo server admin. The Bamboo expiration task is scheduled to run at midnight. Since my job met the expiration (1 day) this morning at 8:43am I am hopeful it will be removed when it runs tonight at midnight. I'll post a follow up confirmation to confirm this is the case and to help any future developers who struggle on this.